# To get transaction id after Successful Paypal Adaptive Payments PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am new to Paypal.

I tried Paypal Adaptive Payments using my paypal sandbox account now. Payment is successful and it is redirected to my paypal return url. But i couldn't get any response like transaction id , transaction status.

How to obtain the response of successful payment using Paypal Adaptive Payments so that i can store the transaction reference id in database?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at Paypal's instant payment notification (IPN)

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Example code in php

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php